# LZ4 library compatibility Issue: java and IOS

Tags: java, ios, swift, compression, lz4

I want to compress data with LZ4 at IOS end and want to decompress the same at Java end.

I used [LZ4 compression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/compression_lz4) with [stream compression method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/compressing_and_decompressing_files_with_stream_compression) for IOS and [jpountz](https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java) () for Java.

It failed at Java end while decompressing. (Looks like LZ4 header is different for both platform.)

Please help!

If not possible, can you please recommend any interoperable LZ4 lib for JAVA and IOS?

Answer (score 2):

LZ4 for IOS and from jpountz both encapsulate data using their own headers.
Since these headers are different, they can't read each other.

You will have to understand each header format, and implement some form of translation layer between the two. Once the headers are fixed, the rest of the payload (the compressed data itself) should be readable.

Another possibility is to use different LZ4 libraries, compliant with the [official LZ4 frame format](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/master/doc/lz4_Frame_format.md). The LZ4 homepage maintains a [list of compliant codecs](https://lz4.github.io/lz4/#interoperable-lz4), one of which is a Java version.

The C reference version can be used on iOS. It's portable, and generally compatible with Objective-C. Use `lz4frame.h` for encapsulation using the official frame format.